# In Laravel Dusk, is there a way to test a link that contains tel: number?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, href, laravel-dusk

I've been searching for a solution to this problem, but I had to ask for myself. If for example, I have this element:

```
<a id="telephone-link" href="tel:+8445291234"><i class="fas fa-phone pr5"></i> (844) 529-1234 </a>
```

So currently, this is how I test it:

```
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit('/')
                ->click('#header-contacts a#telephone-link')
                ->assertPathIs('/');  //9

        $browser->pause(500);
    });
```

But I think this is wrong because there is not a correct test that occurs here. So what I wanted to do is either of the two:

1. To assert if the link really redirects me to a Call application; or
2. If above doesn't work, just check the href value of the link, which I can't find on the documentation.

I hope you can help me. Thank you!

P.S., The same thing could apply on mail: links if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to check if a phone application starts, because you don't have such a application in Dusk (which uses headless chrome).

In my opinion this should be tested by an Feature Test/Unit Test.
Just assert that a method prints out the needed tel: string.

Comment: Thanks, and that's what I would like to know. I want to add that I'm using Laravel 5.5. Which method should I use to check the tel: string? I'm still confused about this...